# Date query on mongodb with Python returns empty

Tags: python, database, mongodb, datetime

I need to fetch data based on specified date from mongodb. When I try code below, I get an empty list. When I check db, I see documents with specified dates.

My code is:

```
db = connect.order_db

select_date_iso = datetime.date(2020,2,18).isoformat()

result = db.koleksiyon.find({u"zaman_pulu": select_date_iso}).sort("zaman_pulu")

for num, doc in enumerate(result):
    print (num, "--", doc, "\n")
```

And a record inside db:

[image]

no error but no data also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB stores dates as the number of milliseconds since epoch.

The Date you are querying, '2020-02-18' would be 1581984000000, while the date in the document is '2020-02-18T23:39:47.761Z' which is 1582069187761.

These don't satisfy an equality match.

You could either us a ranged match of >= '2020-02-18' and < '2020-02-19', or use aggregation with operators like [$dayOfMonth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/index.html#dayofmonth-aggregation) to break down the date into its parts for comparison.